# Is it possible to switch between spaces with Command+Number in Lion?

Tags: macos, spaces

In Snow Leopard I could switch spaces by pressing <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Number</kbd>. Is there a way to turn that on in Lion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can. Just changes the shortcut setting in the **System Preferences>Keyboard>Keyboard Shortcut**. You will find *Mission Control* section for shortcut, and there is entry called *Switch to Desktop*.

You could define your own shortcut here.

Comment: Thank you very much! Can't believe I didn't find that. Fail question.